# Proper way for importing a image(.jpg) dataset Keras, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, keras

For the last few days, I'm working in a Machine Learning project.

I have a dataset of images(.jpg). I have more than 500K images.

Along with that, I have a CSV file contains the name of the images(each image has a unique name) and two labels(target values). The two target labels are completely different and there is no relationship with each other.

I will use model separate models for the two target labels.

My solutions

1. Convert everything into a big CSV file. Like the MNIST dataset in CSV format. The problem with this approach is that the images are big in size(i need big images) and three channeled(color images). So the size of the CSV files becomes super big.
2. Use Keras [ImageDataGenerator & flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) class. As I mentioned earlier that I have two labels(target), so need to create two copies of the same dataset(as flow_from_directory requires a specific structure of the data)

Now, both my solution is working but have specific problems.

I'm wondering that is there any other way to import the dataset. So that I can avoid the problems mentioned above.

I'm using Keras, Pandas, Numpy, and Sklearn for this project. I'm free to use any other library also.

I'm not attaching any code of my solutions with this question. Please let me know if needed.

Thnx
Abhishek

Comment: Code is needed to help you better. Generally what you can do is this: Instead of having the images in the CSV file, add only the path to the image. Then load the images using the path when you need them.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Chatterjee, could you elaborate your question again? This will help you get your solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Pandas, but I don't think that can solve your problem.

Why don't you write your own solution?

You can try implementing the way [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) did.

Take *[Recognizing hand-written digits](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html)* as an example,

#### Example code

```
# Author: Gael Varoquaux <gael dot varoquaux at normalesup dot org>
# License: BSD 3 clause

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics

# The digits dataset 
digits = datasets.load_digits() # <--- right here

images_and_labels = list(zip(digits.images, digits.target))
for index, (image, label) in enumerate(images_and_labels[:4]):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, index + 1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Training: %i' % label)

n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))

classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

classifier.fit(data[:n_samples // 2], digits.target[:n_samples // 2])

expected = digits.target[n_samples // 2:]
predicted = classifier.predict(data[n_samples // 2:])

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))

images_and_predictions = list(zip(digits.images[n_samples // 2:], predicted))
for index, (image, prediction) in enumerate(images_and_predictions[:4]):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, index + 5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.title('Prediction: %i' % prediction)

plt.show()
```

#### Source code

`scikit-learn` build a module called `dataset` only for loading different dataset like MNIST (both images and labels).

You will also have a fun time reading the source code of [dataset.load_digits()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html)

It's **short** and **neat**. Hope you can figure out a better solution.